# Parse response object in web worker using greenlet

Tags: javascript, json, response, worker

[greenlet](https://github.com/developit/greenlet) is a library that moves an async function into its own thread.

```
import greenlet from 'greenlet'

let get = greenlet(async url => {
    // This will run in worker
    let res = await fetch(url)
    return await res.json()
})

console.log(await get('/foo'));
```

And I heard that if I fetch in the main thread and parse in worker, the performance will be very good. So that I try something like

```
let parseInWorker = greenlet(res => new Response(res).json())

let get = async url => {
    let res = await fetch(url)
    return parseInWorker(res)
}
```

But I always get the error : DataCloneError: Response object could not be cloned. I try all solutions such at:

```
let clonedRes = res.clone()
let clonedRes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))
let clonedRes = Object.assign({}, res)
```

but nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

> And I heard that if I fetch in the main thread and parse in worker,
>   the performance will be very good

is not very true, sending something off the the worker, and back from the worker involves some cost, so this needs to be evaluated to consider if there is added performance advantage.

Secondly when you send data to the worker and back to the main thread from worker, they are sent serialised using the [structured cloning algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm). Not everything can be serialised by using this algorithm. I doubt Response can be serialised as well, as it includes streams. Even if it does, sending the response over to web worker will not provide you with any advantages in this particular case